# On primes of specified length and bit pattern

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, big-picture, riemann-hypothesis

Denote $P(n,k)$ to be the number of primes between $2^n$ and $2^{n+1}-1$ having $k$ number of $1$s in its binary expansion between the $n+1$th binary digit and the least which is always $1$ if $n>1$.

It is clear $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}P(i,k)$ is the number of primes bounded by $2^{n+1}$ and satisfies the square root error bound under Riemann Hypothesis.

Is there a similar error bound at every $i,k$ for $P(i,k)$?

Comment: The number of 1s in the expansion of a number is generally known as _Hamming weight_, and while getting that tight of a bound seems unlikely especially at the extremes of $k$, there are in fact things known about them: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22629/are-there-primes-of-every-hamming-weight

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I am asking if there is a Riemann Hypothesis for it and not a complete answer.